# Object to walk forward, turn 180 and walk back

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this object who walks forward, when it gets to a certain x position it should stop, turn 180 degrees and walk back, then when it gets to the position it started at it turns 180 degrees and walk forward again.

This is how i am trying to get him to walk and turn:

```
public float Speed = 1f;
public float TurnSpeed = 1f;

void Start () {
    transform.position = new Vector3(-10, 0, -79);
}

void Update () {
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    if (transform.position.x < -1)
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        transform.Rotate(0, 180 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

He will keep moving and not stop not sure why any help?

Comment: Is there any loop in your program that may be causing this?

Comment: I'm not sure, it should move forward and when the x position reaches -1 it should stop and turn, I'm very new to unity btw

Comment: Why not set waypoints on your map so guards can patrol? Which I assume you want. All your guards can have an array of waypoints and go from one to another (trigger colliders), with pathfinding and AddForce (much healthier then "teleporting" the dude from one place to another, e.g. with moveposition). Then, you just have to transform.LookAt [waypoint gameobject] and there you go. If you want to stay with the vectors, why don't you go for Vector3.MoveTowards instead of the ugly stuff you try to do now? BTW what did you try so far?

Comment: E.g. did you try to Debug.Log(transform.position); to see what really is going on? (I assume you didn't. Do it now and tadaa, you'll see where your stuff goes wrong)

Comment: cheers mate you have assumed the wrong thing btw, he's just a passer by who walk back and forwards, can you suggest and answer

Comment: I've not used unity so I could be completely wrong, but it seems you're doing a translation along the z axis while moving then doing your if comparison on an x axis point. (Which wouldn't have changed)

Comment: but when i put 1,0, 0 he moves along the z axis

Comment: @Mark how do i check the debug.log

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it 'transform.Rotate(0, 180 * Time.deltaTime, 0);' rather than 'transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);' ?

Comment: the if statement is always running, so my player is always rotating, and i don't know why as his position is never -1

Comment: hi @RexDough.  the way you do this is to have two "marker" objects in the scene. "marker" objects are simply empty GameObjects.  name them say "left" and "right".  in your script, have two public variables `public Transform left` and same for right.  **drag** the two items to those slots in the inspector.  then in your script, check if the NPC is left or right of those objects, if so head towards the other one.  ***(you can indeed then have as many of those as you want and it will follow the waypoints)***

Comment: you use "markers" everywhere in unity.  if you have say a car game, you may have dozens of "marker" objects on the car for different reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to the content, but every time you update - your first line says:

Move foreward by one

you need to reverse this after reaching your turningpoint, maybe like this:

```
void Update () {
    static boolean direction;
    if (direction)
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    else
        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, -1) * Speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (transform.position.x < -1) //or whenever you want to turn
        direction = !direction;
}
```

dont forget to rotate or you just walking backwards ;)

Comment: @RexDough insert your coordinates or something other there - not sure when you want to run back. You used: `if (transform.position.x < -1)`

Comment: hi @RexDough you need to TICK this answer since it is correct and generous.